# What's the corresponding commands of gdb's list,disas,x in windbg?

Tags: gdb, windbg

I'm pretty new to windbg ,is there such commands in windbg?

Answer (score 3):

These are mode or less equivalent commands. The arguments for these commands are different, (e.g. range specification), but it is usually easy to learn by trial and error right inside the WinDbg.

- list - print lines from source code file. In WinDbg command is `ls .` (i.e. 'ls' followed by dot). Before using this command you might have to setup reference to source code location using `.srcpath` command, unless you are debugging on the same machine that did the build.
- disas - print assembly instructions. In WinDbg command is `u [address]`. Without address the current EIP/RIP is used.
- x  - examine memory. In WinDbg corresponding commands are:

```
 da - dump ascii
 db - dump bytes
 dd - dump DWords
 dp - dump pointer-sized values
 dq - dump QWords
 du - dump Unicode (16 bit characters)
 dw - dump Words
```

Each command takes an optional address and range as arguments.

Comment: can it take a function name as the argument?

Comment: @gdb, Yes, it can -- function or global/static variable will work as a pointer to address. E.g. command `u kernel32!CreateFileW` will start disassembling CreateFileW function in module kernel32.dll.